# Scala: Is it possible to do a backspace deletion during a println statement?

Tags: scala

This might sound silly, but how to (or can we) use a backspace deletion during `println`:

```
scala> println("123\b")  
123
```

I want to get `12` from the above statement.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with scala println. You can write a custom function that manipulates the string and then do print

Comment: In your example the backspace `\b` actually works, but there is no next character to overwrite the `3` so it is still visible. Try `println("123\bx")` to see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks @jwvh you were the one who first mentioned the answer using println and not printf ;-). Since, then the answer was updated; going to accept it... anyway.... thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add space after backslash b to skip the last digit. It will replace the last one with space,

```
scala> println("123\b ")
12 
scala>
```